# Determine if db query is null

Tags: android, sqlite, null, if-statement

I am trying to write an if statement to determine if the results are null.

```
TabSpec spec4=tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab 4");
        listData[c.getPosition()] = spec4.setIndicator(c.getString(4)) + "\n";
        spec4.setContent(R.id.tab4);


        if (spec4.setIndicator(c.getString(4)) == null){
            tabHost.addTab(spec4);
        }
```

Statement never seems to return true though.  I can see in the database its null.

any ideas?

Comment: So what *is* the value of `spec4.setIndicator(c.getString(4))` and what *is* the value of `c.getString(4)`? Answering both those questions should answer this post.

Comment: @pst, c.getString(4) should be null.. when I look at the database file it shows as null, im not sure if spec4.setIndicator(c.getString(4)) is any different?  I thought that just sets the value of what i put in the ()

Comment: I am asserting that at least one of the assumptions is incorrect. What are the *actual* value at that time? It is either the case that `getString(4)` is not null or `setIndicator(...)` is not null. Both of these can be easily verified.

Comment: once i changed the statement to read if (c.getString(4).equals("null")){
        tabHost.addTab(spec4);
} it worked just fine... so it is "null"..

Comment: The only safe/correct way is to use `isNull` first: From the [Cursor.getString documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html#getString%28int%29): "The result and whether this method throws an exception when the column value is null or the column type is not a string type is implementation-defined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (c.getString(4).equals("null")){
        tabHost.addTab(spec4);
}
```

I had to change == to .equals("null") and it worked!